# c# application works in debug but no in release mode

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have a C# application that references another class to load up excel data like this:

This is the Excel Load Data class:

```
public class LoadExcelDictionary
{
    private Log log = new Log();
    public List<ULTLData> Load(string Input,string OutputDirectory, BackgroundWorker BackgroundWorker)
    {
        List<ULTLData> output = new List<ULTLData>();
        try
        {

            var segmentFull = 0;
            XSSFWorkbook xssfWorkbook;
            using (FileStream file = new FileStream(@Input, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
            {
                //hssfWorkbook = new HSSFWorkbook(file);
                xssfWorkbook = new XSSFWorkbook(file);
            }
            ISheet sheet = xssfWorkbook.GetSheet("Sheet1");
            DataFormatter df = new DataFormatter();
            for (int i = 0; i <= sheet.LastRowNum; i++)
            {
                segmentFull = (((i + 1) * 100) / sheet.LastRowNum);
                //0 is the header row
                if (i > 0)
                {
                    ULTLData uLTLData = new ULTLData
                    {
                        VV = df.FormatCellValue(sheet.GetRow(i).GetCell(0)),
                    };
                    output.Add(uLTLData);
                    Console.WriteLine("Loading Excel Data - " + uLTLData.VV);
                }
                BackgroundWorker.ReportProgress(segmentFull);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Exception: " + e.Message);
            log.Output(e.Message + " " + e.Source);
        }
        return output;
    }
}
```

I reference the Excel data loader from the UI code like this:

```
private void backgroundWorker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    var backgroundWorker = sender as BackgroundWorker;
    segmentFull = 0;
    LoadData ld = new LoadData();
    LoadExcelDictionary led = new LoadExcelDictionary();
    WriteFile wf = new WriteFile();
    try
    {
        var loadedExcel = led.Load(Dictionary, Output, backgroundWorker);
        setStatusLabel("Loading Excel Data Completed");
        log.Output("Loading Excel Data Completed");
    }
    catch (Exception exception)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Exception: " + exception.Message);
        log.Output(exception.Message + " " + exception.Source);
    }
}
```

The problem is that when I run it in debug, the program runs fine and continues after LoadExcelDictionary returns the data. In Release mode, it just does nothing and remains on this line:

> var loadedExcel = led.Load(Dictionary, Output, backgroundWorker);

I am unsure of how I can fix this.

EDIT:

I discovered what the issue was. Its to do with updating the labels. I have this label function that I use:

```
    private void setStatusLabel(string Input)
    {
        if (statusLB.InvokeRequired)
            statusLB.Invoke(new Action(() => statusLB.Text = Input));
        else
            statusLB.Text = Input;
    }
```

This is the cause of my application suddenly stopping. Is this the right way to update a label on the fly?

Comment: My psychic debugging skills tell me that the Excel file you're trying to load data from is located in the "Debug" output folder, so it cannot be found when you run the executable from the "Release" output folder.

Comment: The Excel file that I'm loading comes from a path provided by me in a textbox. It is supposed to read it all and the return a list of data.

Comment: Is it a relative path, or an absolute path? Given the line of code it's failing on, clearly the error is related  to the loading of the file. Do you get any additional information from the debugger? For example, an exception message?

Comment: No exception message. Its an absolute path that i provide. I put in a console.writeline in the loop and it shows that it loads the Excel data and then suddenly it just stops. I then get this message: The thread 0x3bcc has exited with code 0 (0x0).

Comment: I discovered what the issue is. I edited my question with more details. Could you take a look and see if what I did is okay?

Comment: Yes. A label is a control, which means it's part of the UI. You can only access UI controls on the main thread. That's why it isn't working to try and access them from a background thread (the BackgroundWorker). Calling Invoke is a workaround: it performs the operation on the main thread. The deeper problem is why your debugger is not showing you that error message. You have some code that is swallowing exceptions, instead of letting them be handled by the debugger. I would recommend removing that. Only handle exceptions if you can actually handle them (i.e., solve the problem).

Comment: Does that mean I shouldn't pass my Backgroundworker into the LoadExcel function? that exists in a separate class.